# Attempting to set a custom key and value in a Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to do the following in Firebase Real Time Database.
Set a key and value:

```
/authUsers/
{uidSetByMe: 'Custom value"}
```

The code I'm attempting it with is:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.database().ref(`/authUsers`).update({ [userRecord.uid]: userData.uid })
```

The above gives no error it just doesn't work.
I also tried: push

```
admin.database().ref(`/authUsers`).push({ [userRecord.uid]: userData.uid })
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value you want to a `child` call:

```
admin.database().ref('authUsers').child(userRecord.uid).set(userData.uid);
```